# Routing nested resources in Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

In my app, users have messages.

```
resources :users do
   resources :messages
end
```

Users can access their profile with a pretty url, say /albert.

```
match ':username' => 'users#show', :as => 'username'
```

But not their messages!

```
user_message_path(@user, 1)
```

returns /users/1/messages/1. How do I get it to return /albert/messages/1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your routes add:

```
get ':username/messages/:id' => 'messages#show', :as => 'username_message'
```

To access, use `username_message_path`

Comment: thanks but is there a more generic way of doing this? one would have to add that line for each nested resource, which becomes cubersome

Comment: I encourage you to take a look at the definition of the resource method: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Routing/Mapper/Resources.html#method-i-resource (click on show source).  If the patterns it provides is not to your liking, you can create your own custom method tailored to your application.