# What's the proper way to setup routes to get a model through another model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I have 2 models that I would like to setup routes for: Apps and Issues

Apps have many issues and each issue belongs to an App.

I want the URL to represent the fact that issues never come without its app. So something like this:

```
website.com/app-name/issues/2
```

But i'm not sure how to set that up properly in the routes. I also validate the uniqueness of app names, so I won't have any overlap issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd like to use rails nested resources: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#nested-resources

Basically:

```
resources :app do
  resources :issues
end
```

More info on customizing your route to cater to the app name here:

[Routing nested resources in Rails 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6683221/routing-nested-resources-in-rails-3)

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
scope :app_name, :as => '' do 
  resources :issues
end
```

then `rake routes` to see what methods generated